# Why is there two ways of binging a role to a service account in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

If I want to bind a Role(or ClusterRole) to a service account, I can specify it in two different ways.

I can either specify the subject as a `ServiceAccount` like so:

```
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-sa
  namespace: default
```

or do it as a `User` like so:

```
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:default:my-sa
```

What is the difference between the two and is there a preferable way?

Answer (score 0):

A Service Account provides an identity for a process that runs in a pod. Service accounts are not User Accounts.

User Accounts are used by Administrators and Developers etc, to access the cluster and do some dev work or maintenance. Service Accounts are used by applications and processes to authenticate as they talk to the ApiServer. And these Service Accounts can be restricted by way of Kubernetes RBAC. This allows you to authenticate and restrict access and what that process/application can do.

You can read more from this [post](https://medium.com/rahasak/kubernetes-role-base-access-control-with-service-account-e4c65e3f25cc#:%7E:text=User%20Accounts%20are%20used%20by,they%20talk%20to%20the%20ApiServer%20.)

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't answer the question.